# Can we set production mode from localhost in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, localhost, production-mode

I am trying to set `production` **Mode** from my localhost, but it is throwing error.

Can we set Production Mode from localhost? and let us know the precautions before setting the production mode?

[image]

Comment: You have problem with deploying static content. The command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` should return same error. You may have some problems with themes for en_US

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I have same issues and Font awesome'sm less files were creating this folder. Production mode also work if I remove LESS folder from custom-theme's web folder.